# Concatenate repeats first row cell values even though formula selects different cells

Tags: excel, concatenation, pivot-table, excel-2013

I am trying to prep some zip codes to go into the WHERE clause of a SQL query: 
WHERE [Zip_code] IN ()
To do this I put all the values into Excel and want to concatenate the zip codes with an apostrophe at the beginning and an apostrophe, a comma, and a space at the end so 99508 would become '99508', .  So I wrote the equation
=Concatenate("'",D2,"', ") where D2 is the zipcode.  It worked for the top row producing '99058', but when I filled down it still showed the value for D2
[image: Top row only]

To make matters more confusing, when I click on the cells and see the formulas, they are tracking the proper cells but still show data for the top row

[image: Formula not matching output]

I have tried everything that I can think of to solve the problem: reformatting everything as text, formatting the zipcodes as Numbers rather than text, putting the text in the adjoining columns (C2 has an apostrophe, D2 has the Zip code, E2 has apostrophe, comma, and space) and concatenating, using & instead of concatenate ("'"&D2&"', " ), concatenating A on the front and B on the end to do a find and replace, but I still get the same result.  If I select a concatenated cell, click on the formula bar, and press enter the cell shows the proper concatenation, but I would rather not do that for every single cell.

My co-worker suggests including that the zip codes were taken from pivot table outputs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that your workbook is in manual calculation. Did you tried [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[F9] as suggested by pnuts?

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that calculations had somehow been set to manual instead of automatic.

[image]

Switching back to automatic solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
=concatenate("'";D2;"',")
```

idk if gonna work on you sheet, bc i have in spanish my MS-office suite

but if doesn't work, replace the ; for ,

if you copy the formula to the other cells, this must change to the next row

Answer (score -1):

First is clear the worksheet format

secondly, click on file on the excel, then to option, to formula after formula, check the position of the calculation. if its in automatic change it back to Manual and then change it back to automatic.  That will solve it.